# how can I control the styles of the printed page?

Tags: javascript, css

I've added 3 print buttons to my web page, each one printing a portion(div) of the web page.
Here is the code for that

```
function printPage(id)
{
   var html="<html>";
   //html+="<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/template.css" />";
   html+= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
   html+="</html>";

   var printWin = window.open('','_blank','left=0,top=0,width=500,height=500,fullscreen=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status  =0');
   printWin.document.write(html);
   printWin.document.close();
   printWin.focus();
   printWin.print();
   printWin.close();
}


 <input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt"   onClick="printPage('one');" value="Print One">
<input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt"   onClick="printPage('two');" value="Print Two">
<input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt"   onClick="printPage('three');" value="Print three">
```

So when i click on the button 'Print', a new window opens, print successfully and close it.
I have few questions about this

Firstly, i want to popup the print window in the same page. For that i've replaced `_blank` property in `window.open` with `_parent`, but after printing, the page is not redirecting or going back to the page where i've initiated the print. How to avoid this?

Secondly, how can I control the styles of the printed page? I've tried to link a stylesheet (as shown above in the code) but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

---

```
function printPage(printpage)
                {
                    var headstr = '<html><head></head>'+'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/template.css" />'+'<body><br/><br/><br/>';
                    var footstr = "</body>";
                    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
                    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
                    document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;                   
                    window.print();
                    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: For printing style, you can use the `@media print` CSS rule set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a pop-up, you can use a hidden Iframe. That will keep things in the "same page". Make a dummy page "print.html" that already has your stylesheet path in it. If you have the correct path, it will work.

In the print dummy page, make a function that will fetch the HTML content from the parent page (a string called HTMLStuff in this case), then print itself:

```
<iframe id="printf" src="print.html" name="printf"></iframe>

document.body.innerHTML = parent.htmlStuff;
window.print()
```

You can set the SRC of the iframe and make different pages that grab different content. There are other ways to do this, but this is pretty brain-dead simple.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand what you are saying...but just tell me one thing...can't i directly add a stylesheet as shown (in commented) in the code above?

Comment: actually when i tried the above way, some divs are missing in the resulting page..i dont know why..i have 1 table and 2 graphs on that page..when i added the style sheet, the graphs are not showing up

Comment: Open a debugger, such as Firebug, open the NET tab and reload the page. Look for the indication of your stlyesheet loading, or a 404 error. If it's loading there problem lies in your CSS itself.

Comment: it is loading but i don't think there is a problem in css bcos previously i've tried the printpage function in the other way and `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/template.css" />` worked fine there. I've added the previous function that i've used in the question above, have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

To apply a part of your style sheet when rendering the page for print, you can use:

```
@media print {    
    /*
    Your css here
    */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your answer to conform better to the guidelines here. To properly format code (and automatically add some syntax highlighting), you can put four spaces in front of each line. Either in a text editor of your choice or using a shortcut: Ctrl+K.